# React Use State Hook error TypeError: setUser is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

When i press the submit button i am getting this error, **TypeError: setUser is not a function**. I am trying to get the data from a form and store it.

***APP.JS***

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import User from './Components/User';
import Card from './Components/Card';

function App() {

  const {user, setUser} = useState([{username: "", age: 1}]);

  const handleUserAdd = (user1) => {
    setUser(user1);

    console.log(user);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Card>
         <User onUserAdd={handleUserAdd}/>
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

***USER.JS***

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const User = (props) => {

    const {name, setName} = useState("");
    const {years, setYears} = useState(1);

    const handleOnNameChange = (e) => {
        setName(e.target.value);
    }

    const handleOnAgeChange = (e) => {
        setYears(e.target.value);
    }

    const handleOnSubmit = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();

        const user = {
            username: name,
            age: years
        };

        props.onUserAdd(user);

        setName("");
        setYears();
    }

    return ( 
        <>
            <form onSubmit={handleOnSubmit}>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Username:</label>
                    <input class="form-control" aria-describedby="emailHelp" value={name} onChange={handleOnNameChange} />
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Age:</label>
                    <input type="number" min={1} max={120} class="form-control" value={years} onChange={handleOnAgeChange} />
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add User</button>
            </form>
        </>
    );
}
 
export default User;
```

*Screenshot of the error*

[image]

This also happens when i type into the input boxes:
[image]

I've used the useState hook before and it never happened, i'd be grateful if you could help me solve this!

Comment: Check your syntax for `useState`. It returns an array, not an object. `const {user, setUser} = useState([{username: "", age: 1}]);` Should be `const [user, setUser] = useState([{username: "", age: 1}]);`. Same goes for the others.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`useState` returns an array not an object. You should destructure it like this;

```
const [user, setUser] = useState([{username: "", age: 1}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect

```
const { user, setUser } = useState("");
```

This is correct

```
const [user, setUser] = useState("");
```